# Multiprocessing Pool hangs when mapping across a dataframe?

Tags: python, multithreading, pandas, numpy

I'm attemping to split a pandas dataframe into chunks, and then run a function across each chunk in parrallel ([based on this example)](http://chriskiehl.com/article/parallelism-in-one-line/). The regular non-chunked version works just fine (slow), but for some reason, the chunked version fails altogether: the pools hang at 0% CPU usage, and the script never completes. I put together a quick reproducible example if anyone would be so kind as to suggest why this doesnt work?

```
import pandas as pd
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy as np
import time

def samplefunction(dfinputlist):
    dfinputlist=dfinputlist*2
    return dfinputlist

def parallelize_dataframe(df, func):
    df_split = np.array_split(df, 2)
    pool = Pool(4)
    df = pd.concat(pool.map(func, df_split))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return df

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dfinputlist = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,50,size=(100000000, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
    start=time.time()
    dfinputlist=samplefunction(dfinputlist)
    print('Finished Non-Parrallel Version after '+ str(time.time()-start)+' seconds.')
    start=time.time()
    output=parallelize_dataframe(dfinputlist, samplefunction)
    print('Finished Parrallel Version after '+ str(time.time()-start)+' seconds.')
```